# paging like stackoverflow's

Tags: php, pagination, logic, paging

i'm a newbie in php especially on making pagination.

my question is, how to make paging like stackoverflow's pagination?

i mean paging like this :

1 ... 5 6 **7** 8 9 ... 25

(the first number and the last number is always appear, but in the middle only 5 numbers with the selected page absolutely in the middle)

in php i have tried making paging,

```
<?php

//Show page links
for($i=1; $i<=$pages; $i++)
{
    echo '<li id="'.$i.'">'.$i.'</li>';
}

?>
```

but it will be shown all of pages like

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 etc

any body have simple logic example to solve this problem?

many thanks :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Below is a snippet from a [general pagination class](http://www.jensgram.dk/web/e-artikler/1265)<sup>1</sup> I wrote a few years ago. I have edited it to show the relevant parts only.

```
// cntAround is the number of pages to show before and after the current
function renderNavigation($cntAround = 1) {
    $out      = '';
    $isGap    = false; // A "gap" is the pages to skip
    $current  = // Current page
    $cntPages = // Total number of pages

    for ($i = 0; $i < $pages; $i++) { // Run through pages
        $isGap = false;

        // Are we at a gap?
        if ($cntAround >= 0 && $i > 0 && $i < $cntPages - 1 && abs($i - $current) > $cntAround) { // If beyond "cntAround" and not first or last.
            $isGap    = true;

            // Skip to next linked item (or last if we've already run past the current page)
            $i = ($i < $current ? $current - $cntAround : $cntPages - 1) - 1;
        }

        $lnk = ($isGap ? '...' : ($i + 1)); // If gap, write ellipsis, else page number
        if ($i != $current && !$isGap) { // Do not link gaps and current
            $lnk = '<a href="?page=' . ($i + 1) . '">' . $lnk . '</a>';
        }
        $out .= "\t<li>" . $lnk . "</li>\n"; // Wrap in list items
    }

    return "<ul>\n" . $out . '</ul>'; // Wrap in list
}
```

---

**Example 1**

`cntAround = 1`, `current = 5`, `cntPages = 9`:

```
[1] ... [4] 5 [6] ... [9]
```

**Example 2**

`cntAround = 3`, `current = 5`, `cntPages = 11`:

```
[1] [2] [3] [4] 5 [6] [7] [8] ... [11]
```

---

<sup>1)</sup> Article is in Danish. Google Translate'd version [is here](http://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=da&tl=en&u=http://www.jensgram.dk/web/e-artikler/1265).

Comment: Where does $pages is inicialized?

Comment: @dap.tci Oops typo :-S  Should have been `$cntPages`.

Answer (score 15):

This will generate the numbers as per above with current = 7, pages = 25. Replace the numbers with links to get an actual pagination index.

```
$current = 7;
$pages = 25;
$links = array();

if ($pages > 3) {
    // this specifies the range of pages we want to show in the middle
    $min = max($current - 2, 2);
    $max = min($current + 2, $pages-1);

    // we always show the first page
    $links[] = "1";

    // we're more than one space away from the beginning, so we need a separator
    if ($min > 2) {
        $links[] = "...";
    }

    // generate the middle numbers
    for ($i=$min; $i<$max+1; $i++) {
        $links[] = "$i";
    }

    // we're more than one space away from the end, so we need a separator
    if ($max < $pages-1) {
        $links[] = "...";
    }
    // we always show the last page
    $links[] = "$pages";
} else {
    // we must special-case three or less, because the above logic won't work
    $links = array("1", "2", "3");
}
echo implode(" ", $links);
```

Output:

```
1 ... 5 6 7 8 9 ... 25
```

Comment: Thanks. It helps me and save my time too. upvote for you dear.

Answer (score 2):

Somewhat like this(pseudo-code):

```
pg = CurrentPageNo
low = 1
high = MAX_PAGES
if (pg-low <=5)
    output 1 to pg-1 [with links]
else
    output 1..3 [with links]
    output "..."
    output (pg-3) to (pg-1) [with links]

output pg

if (high - pg <=5)
    output pg+1 to high  [with links]
else
    output (pg+1) to high-3 [with links]
    output "..."
    output (high-2) to high [with links]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Zend_Paginator](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.paginator.usage.html) to do just that, and learn to use the Zend Framework while you're at it.

Answer (score 1):

Below is php classes link from where you can download php class for pagination.

http://www.phpclasses.org/search.html?words=paging&x=0&y=0&go_search=1

Answer (score 0):

If you (might potentially) have a large number of pages, consider using "logarithmic" page navigation, as described here (sample code included):

[How to do page navigation for many, many pages? Logarithmic page navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7835752/999120)

(Note that it'll work just fine for small numbers of pages, too, of course!)