# PHP paging show page indicator

Tags: php, mysql, activerecord, paging, indicator

I have lookup many similar script but didn't work

There's current code

```
<?php
   $LimitPerPage = 3;

   $CurrentPage = 1;
   if(isset($_GET['p'])){
      $CurrentPage = $_GET['p'];
   }

   $PageOffset = ($CurrentPage - 1) * $LimitPerPage;
   $image = imagedb::find_all_by_owner($email,array('limit' => $LimitPerPage,'offset' => $PageOffset));
   $TotalPage = ceil(count($linkerimage)/$LimitPerPage);

   if(!is_null($image)){
    // ..show image code
   }
?>
```

How can I develop a navigation bar for switching page?

Eg. Prev [1] **[2]** [3] [4] ... [64] Next

**Bold** is current page.

Comment: You obviously need a loop there and I don't see any.

Comment: How about using the [search](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=limit+per+page) function, e.g. [php-pagination-limit-per-page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11168930/php-pagination-limit-per-page)

Comment: i'm not using php mysql function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can copy the pagination logic from [here](http://www.phpfreaks.com/tutorial/basic-pagination)